# Separating contents while writing a file

Tags: java

Here is a brief explanation of what I want to achieve OVERALL:

Get the contents from a website, remove the unwanted html tags, filtering it.
Then segregating the contents. If it is workstations then I will put it in one file and if its servers than another file.

I will provide a brief overview of the code from the website.

```
   <TR class="RowLight">
      <TD width=0>
         <A href="Report.asp?ReportID=100&amp;sp=Service+Pack+4&amp;os=Microsoft+Windows+2000+Server">
            <IMG border=0 src="images/icolink3.gif" alt="Open the target" width=11 height=11>
         </A>
      </TD>
      <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;Microsoft&nbspWindows&nbsp2000&nbspServer&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;Service&nbspPack&nbsp4&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;30&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR class="RowDark">
      <TD width=0>
         <A href="Report.asp?ReportID=100&amp;sp=&amp;os=Microsoft+Windows+7+Enterprise">
            <IMG border=0 src="images/icolink3.gif" alt="Open the target" width=11 height=11>
         </A>
      </TD>
      <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;Microsoft&nbspWindows&nbsp7&nbspEnterprise&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;794&nbsp;</TD>
   </TR>
```

Till now , my code is capable of getting the above code in a .csv file as

```
Microsoft Windows 2000 Server   Service Pack 4  30
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise        ;        794
```

A ";" is being used in place of a space.

I want the servers and the Windows 7 to be separate. I am unable to get the logic.

Here is my code for filtering out the content (it does not include opening URL connection, bufferwriter, reader etc)

```
  try {
     int i = 0;
     int j = 0;
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (inputLine.contains(s)) {
           j++;

           if (j >= 7) {
              i++;

              String s0 = inputLine;

              String m = "<TD class=SimpleTextSmall>&nbsp;</TD>";
              if (s0.contains(m)) {
                 s0 = " ";
              } else {
                 int startPosition = s0.indexOf(';');
                 int endPosition = s0.indexOf(';', startPosition + 1);
                 s0 = s0.substring(startPosition + 1, endPosition);

                 s0 = s0.replaceAll("&nbsp", " ");
                 s0 = s0.replaceAll(",", "");
              }

              out.write(s0);
              if (i != 3) {
                 out.write(',');
              }

              if (i == 3) {
                 i = 0;
                 out.newLine();

              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Here is what the "j" and "i" mean:

Since I want a new line to be created after every entry, I have a counter (i). It also helps in putting "," for .csv files.

The first seven lines of the webpage contain "s" and I don't need them so I removed them.

I hope this is easy to understand. I have been stuck on this for past two weeks.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the source valid XHTML? If so you can parse it *very* easily with [`DocumentBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) (the API is not as intimidating as it may look, parsing is essentially a one-liner then you use DOM methods to retrieve data), and it will be very straightforward for you to pull out the info you need. If not you could use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for example, and pull out the info just as easily.

Comment: I am not sure but I checked the source code and it started like this.  
<HTML>
 
<HEAD>
<TITLE>View ConfigMgr Reports</TITLE>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<META name="Microsoft Border" content="none, default">
 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript>

Comment: what do you want the output to look like?  can probably be obtained from just parsing through the CSV file.

Comment: @user3329118 Also, can you please add commas (or some other non-whitespace field separator) to your posted output CSV data? It is hard to tell what we are looking at there.

Comment: @user3329118 (BTW, you'd have to use jSoup to parse that because of the unclosed `META` tags, `DocumentBuilder` wouldn't cut it.)

Comment: I added a colon. Sorry for confusion :(

Comment: @user3329118 So it sounds like the *real* question hiding in there is how to split strings like "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise" and "Microsoft Windows 2000 Server" into "Microsoft Windows 7" + "Enterprise" and "Microsoft Windows 2000" + "Server", is this correct? If so that sounds like a job for [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: No no Sorry for confusion I want "Microsoft Windows 2000 Server   Service Pack 4  30" in file 1 and "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise        ;        794" in file two. There are MANY lines of editions so I can't do it manually. Basically anything having the word "server" in file 1 and anything having words such a s"XP" and "7" in file 2.

Comment: @user3329118 Then why not do just that? Since it sounds like you know ahead of time what strings you are looking for, you can decide on all the different patterns you want to match, and open a file for each ahead of time. Then, depending on what pattern the OS name matches, choose the file to write the data out to. Then, close all the files, and you're done.

Comment: I will have a look at jSoup and the parsing suggestions. Thank you :)

Comment: @user3329118 Well jSoup will help you parse but I didn't fully understand your question when I made that comment (sorry) -- you'll still be responsible for coming up with the same logic to determine what entry goes to what file.